# как можно пропустить первую итерацию в цикле js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 {this.state.data.kpi.map(item => <tr className={this.activeRow(item)}>

                                                <td>{item.client}</td>
                                                <td>{item.all_incidents}</td>
                                                <td>{item.incidents_in_work}</td>
                                                <td>{item.expired_incidents}</td>
                                                {this.kpiCell(item)}
                                                <td>{item.manager}</td>
                                                {this.buttonView(item)}
                                            </tr>)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через метод `slice`:

```
{this.state.data.kpi.slice(1).map(item =>
  // тут много jsx-а
</tr>)}
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!